# equal condition with c:if not working

Tags: jsf, if-statement, primefaces

I want check to information from a bean in booth of them are 4 but it's not working .
I use primefaces 3.5 and jsf 2.1

```
<c:if test="#{task.FROM_USER.ID == taskboxBean.loginUser.ID}">
            <p:outputLabel value="Equal"/>
            <ui:repeat var="task_to_user" value="#{task.TASKBOX_TO_USERS}">
                    <p:outputLabel value="#{task_to_user.USER.EMAIL}" />
            </ui:repeat>
        </c:if>

        <c:if test="#{task.FROM_USER.ID != taskboxBean.loginUser.ID}">
                <p:outputLabel value="not equal"/>
            <p:outputLabel value="#{task.FROM_USER.EMAIL}" />
        </c:if>
```

Comment: JSTL tags are evaluated during build-phase and not during rendering-phase. Do you change the values you compare after build-phase? What happens if you replace the jstl tag by a `<h:panelGroup>`?

Comment: thank you i replaced it and it worked thanks ;)

Answer (score 1):

Solution

```
        <h:panelGroup rendered="#{task.FROM_USER.ID == taskboxBean.loginUser.ID}">              
            <ui:repeat var="task_to_user" value="#{task.TASKBOX_TO_USERS}">
                    <p:outputLabel value="#{task_to_user.USER.EMAIL}" />
            </ui:repeat>
        </h:panelGroup>

        <h:panelGroup rendered="#{task.FROM_USER.ID != taskboxBean.loginUser.ID}">

            <p:outputLabel value="#{task.FROM_USER.EMAIL}" />
        </h:panelGroup>
```